# Array base index addressing in NASM

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to iterate through a defined "2d" array and find the smallest value.

I get errors while trying to access the value inside the matrix.
Note that I have tried replacing:

```
mov ecx, matrix[edi + esi *2]
```

with

```
mov ecx, [matrix + edi + esi * 2]
```

and it did not help

```
;-----------------------------------------------
;SECTION .DATA
;Instantiated variables/Constants
;-----------------------------------------------
section .data

result:     db "The smallest number is: " , 0x0a
result_len:     equ $-result

nl:     db "   ", 0x0a
nl_len  equ $-nl

matrix: dw  25, 24, 23, 22, 21
        dw  20, 19, 18, 17, 16 
        dw  15, 14, 13, 12, 11 
        dw  10,  9,  8,  7,  6
        dw   5,  4,  3,  2,  1


;-----------------------------------------------
;SECTION .BSS
;Non initialized variables
;-----------------------------------------------
section .bss


;-----------------------------------------------
;SECTION .TEXT
;Code
;-----------------------------------------------
section .text
global _start 

_start: 
    ;variable declaration
    mov edi, 0
    mov esi, 0
    mov ecx, 9

outerLoop:
    cmp edi, 50                  ;each element is 2 bytes (2 ascii characters)
    jg  endloop                  ;we need 50 because it's 5 elements per row
    mov esi, 0                   ;and 5 rows
innerLoop:
    cmp esi, 5                   ;Compare esi(inner loop index) to 5
    jge innerEnd                 ;jump if it reached the end of the row
    mov eax, matrix[edi + esi*2]
    cmp [eax], ecx
    jg  biggerThan
    mov ecx, [eax]
biggerThan:
    inc esi
    jmp innerLoop
innerEnd:
    add edi, 10                  ;row has been complete, go to next
    jmp outerLoop

endloop:
    push    ecx

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, result
    mov edx, result_len
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, esp
    add [ecx], DWORD 48
    mov edx, 2
    int 0x80

    ; display new line
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, nl
    mov edx, nl_len
    int 0x80

 exit:
    mov eax, 1          ;eax contains 1 so quit
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80
```

If someone could explain why this line

```
mov eax, matrix[edi + esi*2]
```

it isn't working or how I should go about
iterating through the array and finding the smallest, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mov eax, matrix[edi + esi*2]
cmp [eax], ecx
jg  biggerThan
mov ecx, [eax]
```

Nasm wants all of a memory reference within the square brackets, so `mov eax, [matrix + edi + esi * 2]` should be correct. But you're moving 4 bytes from memory - two of your values - into `eax`. You only want two bytes. `cmp [eax], ecx` however, tries to compare `ecx` with memory at the address in `eax`, which is almost certainly not valid memory. You probably want something more like...

```
mov ax, [matrix + edi + esi*2]
cmp ax, cx
jg  biggerThan
mov cx, ax
```

Your display routine is only going to work for a single digit. Since the smallest value in your matrix is only a single digit, this may not cause a problem.

Look up the difference between `jg` and `ja`. Your values are all positive, so you may mean to treat them as unsigned - `ja` would be correct. If you propose to allow negative numbers, `jg` is correct. If your values are positive and less than 2G either would work, but you might as well learn the difference.

You're on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

to find the smallest is a basic algorithm, Just put the initial value of the array, into a "smallest variable" then compare the next one, if the next one if smaller then save it into the "smallest variable" if it isn't, then skip it and go onto the next item in the array.

For the items in the array, you're probably just not using the correct memory address. Ahhhh the beauty of assembly programming